# Выпадающий список в EditText

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-ui

Как лучше организовать выпадающий список в `EditText` при вводе текста, подобный полю для ввода url в браузерах (когда внизу поля всплывают подходящие url'ы)?

Есть ли такой функционал в стандартном `EditText`?

Лучшее, что пришло в голову, это добавить обычный `ListView` в `Layout` ниже `EditText`, и при вводе текста показывать/скрывать его.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь классом [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) . Это наследник `EditText`, специально предназначенный для вашей цели. В сети можно найти много примеров его использования. [Краткий пример](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete) с официального сайта